# How to perform calculations on time series data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a CSV file containing the daily depletion of a battery from its maximum capacity (EnergySum column). I am trying to calculate the hourly charge rate for this battery back to its total capacity based on numbers on column Capacity.

The steps for this process are as below:

Read the number on column Capacity. If it's less than EnergySum, add its number to the Charged column and move to the next row.

When you reach a row that its capacity will exceed EnergySum, add the fraction required to reach EnergySum and assign zero for the next rows in that day.

Repeat this process for other days.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Date Capacity  EnergySum
2020-04-09 00:00:00       0.0   9.032593
2020-04-09 01:00:00       0.0   9.032593
2020-04-09 02:00:00       0.0   9.032593
2020-04-09 03:00:00       0.0   9.032593
2020-04-09 04:00:00       0.0   9.032593
...                       ...        ...
2020-10-11 19:00:00       2.4  30.972939
2020-10-11 20:00:00       2.3  30.972939
2020-10-11 21:00:00       2.2  30.972939
2020-10-11 22:00:00       2.1  30.972939
2020-10-11 23:00:00       2.0  30.972939
```

And the desired output for the first day will look like this:

```
Date  EnergySum  Capacity   Charged
0   04-09  00:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
1   04-09  01:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
2   04-09  02:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
3   04-09  03:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
4   04-09  04:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
5   04-09  05:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
6   04-09  06:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
7   04-09  07:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
8   04-09  08:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
9   04-09  09:00:00   9.032593       0.0  0.000000
10  04-09  10:00:00   9.032593       2.2  2.200000
11  04-09  11:00:00   9.032593       2.2  2.200000
12  04-09  12:00:00   9.032593       2.2  2.200000
13  04-09  13:00:00   9.032593       2.2  2.200000
14  04-09  14:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.232593
15  04-09  15:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
16  04-09  16:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
17  04-09  17:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
18  04-09  18:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
19  04-09  19:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
20  04-09  20:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
21  04-09  21:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
22  04-09  22:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
23  04-09  23:00:00   9.032593       2.2  0.000000
```

Data generation:

```
data = {'Date':
 ['04-09  00:00:00','04-09  01:00:00','04-09  02:00:00','04-09  03:00:00','04-09  04:00:00','04-09  05:00:00','04-09  06:00:00','04-09  07:00:00','04-09  08:00:00','04-09  09:00:00','04-09  10:00:00','04-09  11:00:00','04-09  12:00:00','04-09  13:00:00','04-09  14:00:00','04-09  15:00:00','04-09  16:00:00','04-09  17:00:00','04-09  18:00:00','04-09  19:00:00','04-09  20:00:00','04-09  21:00:00','04-09  22:00:00','04-09  23:00:00'],
'EnergySum':
[9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593,9.032593],
'Capacity':
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I can't find a way to apply my method in a way that each day is processed separately, and everything resets when a new day starts.

Comment: When you are pasting dataframe here by copying from your notebook/code. Use the output from print(df.to_string()) instead of print(df). The column names align properly with the values for better readability

Comment: Have you tried pandas groupby method?

Comment: @Asettisriharsha I have used groupby to clean the data and bring it to its current shape and form (to make the calculations more straightforward). But I couldn't find a way to both group by days and apply an if condition or a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assume df is your input dataframe.

Try grouping it on each day and use pd.concat to get the grouped dataframes into single output.

```
ouput = pd.DataFrame()
for group,t in df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date):
    #Apply the operation on the dataframe t - add code here
    output = pd.concat([ouput,t])
```